# Kill sh -c and all its sub processes in c with linux system calls

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on this status bar program that needs to fork and exec bash scripts using job control. It then pipes the output to a string and displays it. I'm currently implementing this timeout functionality that starts a timer and then kills the started process if they takes too long to exit.

The processes are started like this :

```
if (pipe2(pipefd, O_CLOEXEC) == -1)                                     
    return -1;                                                               int pid;                                                                
if ((pid = fork()) == -1)                                               
    return -1;                                                      
if (pid == 0) {                                                         
        close(STDIN_FILENO);                                            
        close(STDERR_FILENO);                                           
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);                                 
        setpgid(0, 0);                                                  
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);                        
        _exit(127);                                                     
}                                                                       
return pid;
```

And killed like this :

```
kill(cpid, SIGKILL);
```

However, this code won't kill sh's sub processes and that's a big problem. To add to that it creates a lot of defunct sh processes even though I'm using waitpid.

Comment: This is one of the things that process groups are for. See `killpg`, and https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Group-Functions.html

Comment: BTW, using SIGKILL is a bad idea -- particularly if you haven't even tried SIGTERM first. When you kill a program hard, it has no chance to flush its buffers, so you can have output that it's tried to print but hasn't flushed yet simply be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Kill the entire process group by using the negative of the process group leader:

```
kill(-cpid, SIGKILL);
```

Comment: So the pid needs to be negative. Thanks a lot

Comment: @WilliamBoulanger, making it negative is how you specify you're passing a process group number, not a process id number. You can't use an arbitrary process id number as if it were a process group; you need to be passing, _specifically_, the process group number (which happens to be the same as the process id number of the leader of that process group, if your OS is Linux).

Comment: Now it kills every sub process except for the actual sh process, which becomes defunct or a zombie process.

Comment: @WilliamBoulanger, if it's a zombie, that means you haven't `wait()`ed for it. Literally, an entry in the process table waiting to be read and removed by a `waitpid()` call is what a zombie _is_.

Comment: @WilliamBoulanger That should have happened with the original code, too.

Comment: That's weird cause I wait for it : waitpid(cpid, 0, 0);

Comment: Unless you need to get the exit status, you can prevent zombies by setting `SIGCHLD` to `SIG_IGN`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, setting the pgid with setpgid(0, 0); will ensure that the child has a pgid equal to his pid. Then, when it forks, they will share that same pgid and that' why they're all killed?

Comment: Yes, that's how process groups work. Unless `setpgid` or `setsid` is called in a process, it inherits the process group from its parent.

Comment: @Barmar So I just did this, but I still have a couple questions if you don't mind. Baiscally, the reason I use waitpid is to ensure that the program has terminated before reading the pipe, but I don't care about the exit status. So my thought is that it doesn't matter if the process is killes or terminates successfully, cause in the end it'll wait for anything to happen to the process. Thing is, when I kill the process manually, it definitely waits til that happens, but the process becomes a zombie. However, it doesn't when it terminates successfully.

Comment: Maybe I should waitpid the entire group

Comment: you can't wait for a group. But you should be calling `waitpid` *after* you call `kill`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235319/discussion-between-william-boulanger-and-barmar).